# Differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y),y(0)=y(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y),y(0)=y(1)=0$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous. Then

$1.$ $y(x)=0$ if and only if  $x\in (0,1)$

$2.$ $y$ is bounded

$3.$ $y$ is strictly increasing.

$4.$ $y^{'}$ is unbounded.

Please help me. Can i say that $y$ must be bounded by given boundary conditions?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you having trouble? What background material do you know about? Please don't just pose a question with no thoughts or efforts shown. However, notice that the system *only* depends on the current state, so if it starts increasing, how can it come back down through that same $y$-value?

Comment: i already said that according to me its bounded as boundary conditions..

Comment: To be fair, you didn't say that - you asked it. What relevant background results do you know? Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Note that 1. & 3. can be eliminated purely from the fact that $y(0) = y(1) =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the unique solution.

Suppose $f(0) >0$, then $y$ has a $\max$ at some $x^* \in (0,1)$, and
$y'(x^*) = f(y(x^*)) = 0$, with $y(x^*) >0$.

However, since
$x \mapsto y(x^*)$ and $y$ satisfy the differential equation with initial
condition $y(x^*)$ we must have $y = y(x^*)$ which is a contradiction.

If we assume $f(0)<0$ we obtain a similar contradiction.

Hence $f(0) = 0$, from which we obtain $y=0$.

(Note that Condition 1. can never hold since $y(0) = 0$.)

**Note**: From the above we can see that if a solution $y$ has a local maximum
or minimum at $x^*$ with $x^* \in (0,1)$, then the solution is constant.
Hence any non constant solution must lie strictly between the boundary conditions and is monotone.

Comment: how its solution is unique??

Comment: its boundary value problem...

Comment: It satisfies a first order differential equation with a specified initial condition and is Lipschitz.

Comment: ok sir....thanks a lot...